# Is it possible to create unlimited billing plans into paypal?

Tags: node.js, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using the PayPal subscription feature I read in the documentation of PayPal. I've created multiple plans for which users can subscribe.

In my application flow, I provide the ability for a user to create their own plans but I'm a little confused about PayPal's limitations.

Does PayPal allow me to create unlimited billing plans on a single Developer Account?

Answer (score 0):

If by billing plans you mean the setup of cycles and frequency of charging for a product: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#3-create-a-plan

Then yes that is correct. There is no set limit to how many different plans you can create.

Plans can't be deleted, they can only be deactivated, so don't go to crazy with plans you aren't going to be needing.

Comment: my question is not related to cycles or frequency. is there is any limitation on plan creation eg: PayPal allows the user to create 10,20,30 or 100 plans or unlimited?

Comment: Different cycles and frequency, and well amounts and products too, what creating Billing plans are for, so I'm making sure this is what you mean by creating plans. And as I said, there's no set limit.